# How do I make the letters in my material-ui button not all capitalized?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In my code, the letters in the word "Add" are not all capitalized

My code:

[image]

but when it renders it capitalizes all.

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to apply `text-transform` css in the buttons style.

```
<Button sx={{ml:6, textTransform: 'lowercase'}}>Add</Button>
```

I used `lowercase` in the example, but you may use [other](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) values.

Answer (score 3):

use `textTransform` property in styles

```
<Button sx={{ml:6, textTransform: 'capitalize'}}>Add</Button>
```